# Data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

there are two tables:

TABLE **cars**

```
id | date
----------
1 | 2012-01-04
2 | 2012-01-04
3 | 2012-01-05
```

TABLE **versions**

```
id_car | year | author
-------------------------
1 | 2005 | John
1 | 2001 | Carl

2 | 2003 | Carl
2 | 2001 | John

3 | 2004 | Carl
3 | 2003 | John
```

I need to get all the information about cars with yesterday's date (2012-01-04) and information about their latest version if author is Carl.

So in this example I need to get:
**2 | 2012-01-04 | 2003 | Carl**

Comment: I used this to get my head around joins -> http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html hope you find it useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want an `inner join`:

```
select
    c.id,
    c.date,
    v.year,
    v.author
from
   cars c
   inner join versions v on
       c.id = v.id_car
   inner join (
        select 
            id_car, 
            max(year) as latestYear 
        from 
            versions 
        group by 
            id_car
    ) vmax on
       c.id = vmax.id_car
       and v.year = vmax.latestYear
where
   v.author = 'Carl'
   and c.date = '2012-01-04'
```

In this query, you're saying, "Grab me everything from `cars` where the date is `2012-01-04` and then find everything in `versions` where the `id_car` column is equal to my `id` column in `cars`. Oh, and only give me anything from `versions` where the author is `Carl`, but only where the year of the car is equal to the greatest year of the car that's available."

Comment: This will return 2 rows from table versions: 1 | 2001 | Carl and 2 | 2003 | Carl. I need only second one